# Cauchy-Schwarz for Multiple Integrals

Tags: analysis

Is there a generalization of the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for multiple integrals?

Comment: You mean like $|\iint f\overline g|\leq\sqrt{\iint|f|^2}\sqrt{\iint|g|^2}$ on subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and higher dimensional analogues?  If so, then yes, these are all special cases of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy-schwarz

Answer (score 1):

According to [Michael Steele](http://books.google.com/books?id=7GDyRMrlgDsC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=cauchy%20schwarz%20multiple%20integrals&source=bl&ots=2f4B2EUeuQ&sig=Cm6iDtaassOPf-5jRF3cHpY1W3M&hl=en&ei=Rw2ZTe3ILY_pgQeK79G7CA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q&f=false), one generalization is the following for double integrals: $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2, f: S \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: S \to \mathbb{R}$, then $$A = \iint_{S} f^{2} \ dx \ dy, \ B = \iint_{S} fg \ dx \ dy, \ C = \iint_{S} g^{2} \ dx \ dy$$ satisfy $|B| \leq \sqrt{A} \cdot \sqrt{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

There is an exact generalisation: for any space of functions over a measure space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ where $ \int_X \lvert u \rvert^2 \, d\mu = 0 $ if and only if $u =0$, then if we write $\langle u,v \rangle = \int_X \bar{u}v \, d\mu$, we have
$$ \langle u,v \rangle^2 \leqslant \langle u,u \rangle \langle v,v \rangle, $$
with equality if and only if $u=kv$ for some constant $k$.

If $\langle u,u \rangle=0$ or $\langle v,v \rangle=0$, this is clear. Suppose now neither is zero. Then
$$ \frac{\lvert \langle u,v \rangle \rvert}{\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle \langle v,v \rangle}} = \left\lvert \int_X \frac{\bar{u}}{\sqrt{\langle u,u \rangle}} \frac{v}{\sqrt{\langle v,v \rangle}} \right\rvert \, d\mu \leqslant \left\lvert \frac{1}{2}\int_X \left( \frac{\lvert u \rvert^2}{\langle u,u \rangle} +  \frac{\lvert v \rvert^2}{\langle v,v \rangle} \right) \right\rvert \, d\mu = 1, $$
using the elementary AM-GM inequality $ 2\lvert ab \rvert \leqslant \lvert a \rvert^2+ \lvert b \rvert^2$. It is clear that equality holds precisely when the functions are proportional, by the conditions of the AM-GM inequality.

---

A more direct way in this case is to note
$$ 0 \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\iint \lvert u(x)v(y)-u(y)v(x) \rvert^2 \, d\mu(x) \, d\mu(y) = \langle u,u \rangle \langle v,v \rangle-\lvert \langle u,u \rangle\rvert^2, $$
obviously with equality only if $u(x)v(y)-u(y)v(x) = 0$, so $u(x)=kv(x)$.